# Lots of same 3 processus : migration, ksoftirqd, watchdog on Fedora

Tags: fedora, process

On a Fedora 11, I have more than 250 processes: migration, ksoftirqd and watchdog.

They are not taking any CPU or memory resources, just sleeping.

What is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are per cpu kernel threads. If you 16 CPUs you will get following output (see thread numbers from 0 to 15)

```
# ps aux | grep migration
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:27 [migration/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   1:07 [migration/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:38 [migration/2]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:22 [migration/3]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:23 [migration/4]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:06 [migration/5]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:01 [migration/6]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:01 [migration/7]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:04 [migration/8]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:29 [migration/9]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:19 [migration/10]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:12 [migration/11]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:09 [migration/12]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:19 [migration/13]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:16 [migration/14]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb22   0:09 [migration/15]
```

You will find similar output for ksoftirqd, watchdog and other per-cpu-kernel threads.

The problem is when you start seeing them in top eating some CPU. Are you?. That actually means you have big load on your server.

Comment: It has a dual intel quad core, so 16 threads, that explains why I have 16 of each process like : events, kintegrityd, kblockd, ata, aie, crypto, kmpathd !

Thanks !